# Is the Hamiltonian a pure boundary term in linearised gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, hamiltonian-formalism, gravitational-waves, adm-formalism

It's well-known that in general relativity, the Hamiltonian consists purely of a boundary term: the so-called [ADM Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism). This is because the bulk term is an integral of the constraint operator $\mathcal{H}$, which vanishes on-shell.

Is the same true in [linearised gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity)? That is, suppose we fix a background $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ and decompose the metric as $g_{\mu\nu} = \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ with $h_{\mu\nu}$ a small perturbation. Then is the leading-order dynamics for $h_{\mu\nu}$ generated by a Hamiltonian which is a pure boundary term? Or does splitting the metric in this way somehow break this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearised gravity action is the Fierz-Pauli action $\newcommand{\p}{\partial}$
$$S_\text{FP}[h] = \int\mathrm{d}^4 x \left(-\frac12 \p_\mu h^\rho_{~\rho} \p_\nu h^{\mu\nu} + \frac12 \p_\lambda h^{\mu\nu} \p_\nu h_{\mu\lambda} + \frac14\p_\mu h^\rho_{~\rho} \p^\mu h^\lambda_{~\lambda} - \frac14\p^\lambda h^{\mu\nu}\p_\lambda h_{\mu\nu} \right).$$

The induced Hamiltonian on a spatial slice $\Sigma$ is indeed a boundary term, namely
$$H_\Sigma = -\frac12\int_\Sigma \mathrm{d}^3 x\ \mathcal{H}(x) = \frac12 \int_{\partial \Sigma} \mathrm{d}S_m \Big(\partial_n  h^{mn} -\partial^m h^{n}_{~n}\Big).$$
This is derived, for instance, in reference [1].

---

References: [1] V. Benedetti, H. Casini, J. M. Magan, *Generalized symmetries of the graviton*, [arxiv:2111.12089](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12089)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!